# Defining a function as the integral of a differential one-form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, line-integrals

> Deﬁne $f(x,y)=\int_c (2\xi\eta)d\xi + (\xi^2 −\eta^2)d\eta$ where $c$ is the straight line path from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$.
>
> Compute $f(x,y)$ and its differential $df$ (in terms of $(x,y)$).

Normally, I know how to compute $f(x,y)$ and its differential if the provided one-form is in terms of $x$ and $y$, but in this problem the one-form uses $\xi$ and $\eta$, even though the function $f$ uses $x$ and $y$? I'm not sure I understand how this works and how it will change the procedure of solving the integral.

Comment: Would you be comfortable with something like $g(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \ dt$? Same idea

Comment: So you would be able to calculate $\int (2xy)\,dx+(x^2-y^2)\,dy$ along a straight line from $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$? Do it!